# Is there a similar proverb in English as of malayalam

Tags: popular-refrains

In Malayalam, there is a proverb "**Whether the leaf falls on a thorn or a thorn on a leaf, the leaf is always harmed.**" Can you suggest an English saying similar to this?

Comment: Can you describe what the "proverb" mean (figuratively)?

Comment: This is a proverb, which is usually used to warn a person of lower status while dealing with a person of higher status.

Comment: @Antony  How intriguing! I am thinking that the first word should perhaps be 'Whether'. In which case it makes perfect sense. Even if  a weaker individual wins a quarrel with a stronger person, the weaker one will be harmed in some way. Is that what it means?

Comment: @Antony I believe that Malayalam is the language spoken in the Indian state of Kerala. Also I understand that Kerala is the only state of India which has had a communist government. Some years ago I read Arundhati Roy's 'The God of Small Things' which describes a society in which communism exists in conflict with the caste system. Seems as if this proverb is in some sense integral to that juxtaposition. I am afraid I cannot think of any expression in English which is equivalent to your proverb.

Comment: @WS2 It is an old saying and you can read it in a different sense like giving warning to a person before dealing with anything, that might harm the person.
please don't read it with communism and caste system.

Comment: It's '**Whether** the leaf ...':  *Whether the leaf falls on a thorn or a thorn on a leaf, it's the leaf that is harmed.*

Comment: @WS2 It has nothing to do with any of those things. It's of **universal** relevance.

Comment: @Kris I'm sure that it is. But can you think of any similar proverb in English?

Comment: Less threatening:  "Six of one; half a dozen of the other" ?

Comment: Maybe "Shit rolls downhill,"   or "You can't fight City Hall."  I'm not sure there is as poetic a saying in AmericanEnglish, but I intend to start using this translation.  I like it!

Comment: It’s a bit similar to (but much nicer than) the recent (and ***very offensive!***) meme that fighting on the Internet is like competing in the Special Olympics: even if you win, you’re still a retard. The intentions are completely opposite: yours is intended to protect the person being addressed from fighting a battle that can’t possible bring them anything good, while the Internet meme is just meant to put someone down. But they both carry the basic meaning of _“win or lose, you still lose”_.

Comment: "Whoever you vote for, the Government gets in".

Answer (score 6):

From poker/casino play there is "The house always wins."

Answer (score 3):

**"[Damned if you do, damned if you don't.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Damned+if+you+do,+damned+if+you+don%27t)"** might fit

> *Prov.* No matter what you do, it will cause trouble.

---

How about **"throwing an egg against a rock"** ? I couldn't find a definition but it is used in some of the sources and books.

For example, in this book about Chinese Philosophy (The Ways of Confucianism: Investigations in Chinese Philosophy *By David S. Nivison*):

[image]

Comment: "Throwing an egg against a rock," is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

"No-win situation" might suit you.

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-win_situation